# Fetch value from database into dynamically added row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new in `PHP` programming, 
Now I am creating program for billing system. 
I have created a table and adding row into table dynamically, this works fine.
Now i want to add values from database to that dynamically added row, please tell me how to add values.
Here is my code of form

```
      <form style="margin-left: 200px; padding: 10px; background: yellow;     width:         500px;" action="bill.php" method="post" name="transaction" id="transaction">
        <span style="color: black">Receipt      No:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="rcptNo" id="rcptNo" /></br></br>

        <label for="student name"><span style="color: black">Customer Name:</span></label>
        <select name="st_name" id="st_name">
            <option value="">Select..</option>  
        </select></br></br>
        <label for="academic year"><span style="color: black">Academic Year:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <select name="acad_year" id="acad_year">
            <option value="">Select..</option> 
        </select></br></br>
        <label for="item name"><span style="color: black">Item Name:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</label>
        <select name="item_name" id="item_name">
            <option value="">Select..</option>    
        </select>

        <input type="button" name="addItem" id="addItem" value="ADD ITEM"  /></br></br>
        <!--<div id="items1"><b></b></div>-->

        <table id="items" border="2" width="400px" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">

            <tr>
                <!--<th>Sr.No</th>-->
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Unit Cost</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

And here is `JQUERY` code

```
var cnt = 2;
$("#addItem").click(function() {       
        $('#items tr').last().after('<tr><td>' + cnt + '</td><td>' + cnt + '</td><td><input type="text" name="txtbx' + cnt + '" value="' + cnt + '"></td></tr>');
        cnt++;
});
```

So please tell me, how can i add the item name and unit price from database to that dynamically added row?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: send ajax call ti get data and then set in the row

Comment: You mean currently your table is empty and you want to fetch data(row) from db and add row to the table each time you click on the button, right?

Comment: yes right............

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a SQL database. What flavor of SQL is it?

One way you could do it is to use an Ajax call to grab the database info, and then use that in your dynamically created table.

Your ajax could look something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://locationofyourdbhook",
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      $('#items tr').last().after('<tr><td>' + data.cnt + '</td><td>' + data.cnt +        '</td><td><input type="text" name="txtbx' + data.cnt + '" value="' + data.cnt + '"></td>  </tr>');
    cnt++;
    }
  });
```

Comment: which url i have to use

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `PHP` page to retreive your database data. For example `database.php`.
Then send an `ajax` request to that page as shown below.
From the `ajax` response you can add details to row.

```
var cnt = 2;
$("#addItem").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "database.php",
    }).done(function(data){
        if (data) {
            $('#items tr').last().after('<tr><td>' + data.cnt + '</td><td>' + data.cnt + '</td><td><input type="text" name="txtbx' + data.cnt + '" value="' + data.cnt + '"></td>  </tr>');
            cnt++;
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE : For ajax reference:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: i want in php not in asp

Comment: Yeah I haven't mentioned anything about asp here. Its jquery. Hope you know how to retreive db values using php.

Comment: yes but i want data of a perticular id so what will be the sql query for that SELECT item_name,unit_price FROM item_master is this correct

Comment: SELECT item_name,unit_price FROM item_master WHERE column_id = your_id_value

Comment: i want it dynamic SELECT item_name,unit_price FROM item_master WHERE id = $id but it gets error that is undefined index id pls help me